# TeXworks inactive after hibernate

Tags: texworks

I'm using TeXworks 0.6.2 (MiKTeX 2.9.6800 64-bit) under Windows 10. When I stop working I hibernate my system so I need not reopen all the programs after a break. 
Sporadically TeXworks is inactive when waking up from hibernate so I have to kill the task with the task manager. My theory was: The problem occurs more frequently when I stop working at university in the afternoon and start again at home in the evening, so the system wakes up in a different network environment. 
Not convincing for 2 reasons: 1. All other programs work fine, why only TeXworks? 2. In Corona times I work at home only. No changes after hibernate. However my wifi has a 2.4[image] and 5 GHz band so the system might still connect to different networks.

See task manager status of two cases (German texts but inactive should be clear). 
My computer is a HP Omen laptop, same behaviour was before with a DELL without nvidia card. Frequency of the problem: 10 %.

[image: 4]

Comment: Your TeXworks is not completely up to date. I have TeXworks 0.6.5 (MiKTeX 2.9.7420 64-bit). Problems like this are issues that I would report directly to the developer, they are usually the best to deal with these sorts of things. But if you do that you may be asked to verify that this occurs with the current release version (in case it is a bug that has already been resolved).

Comment: Isn't this question more suitable for other SE sites?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to avail yourself with the latest version of Miktex to see if its a bug issue that has been corrected by the developers[basic-miktex-2.9.7442-x64.exe](https://miktex.org/download/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/setup/windows-x64/basic-miktex-2.9.7442-x64.exe)

Comment: I have updated to TeXWorks 0.6.5, and the problem has disappeared for the last 2 weeks - almost: TeXworks is fine, but once Acrobat Reader which is used as the rendering software was inactive after hibernate.
My theory: TeXworks is not the culprit but Acrobat. The new version of TeXworks gets along better with the Acrobat problem.